# Change DNS records and point to my AWS instance

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I'm taking over a project and I cannot access the original Amazon AWS account, which has a route53 configuration of DNS nameservers and A records configurations. I'm fairly new to networking but I was wondering if i can redirect the dns configurations to my instance? Maybe I'm wrong but I feel like if I change the nameservers to point to my instance I can set the remaining A records configurations on my instance and the result will point to mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to your domain registrar (ie any domain registrar except aws) you can update dns to point to other nameservers and then setup your dns as required on your new dns.

Before you do that ensure you backup any dns entries you might need for email, web, verification codes in txt records etc (including each subdomain). As you don't have access to backup dns you can fake it by using dig to return any known existing records: 
https://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=example.com%0D%0Awww.example.com&type=ANY&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4
Ignore the NS and SOA values, you will be assigned new ones when you setup the dns zone elsewhere.

I'd advise against hosting your dns on your server but your thinking is correct.  Use aws route53, setup a new zone in your own aws account , this will provide you with a hosted zone containg your new name server NS and a "start of authority" SOA record. Create whatever dns records you require in your copy, then in your domain control panel enter the nameservers from above. Depending on the TTL of existing dns entries/It will take some time for everyone to start using the new dns (dig above shows TTL of each record) but it should be pretty strait forward. Good luck!